# Azure Blueprint Assignment is stuck in "Deploying" state - frozen in an infinite loop

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blueprints

After creating a new blueprint assignment for an existing blueprint, my blueprint assignment is stuck in the "Deploying" state for over an hour (should have taken 4-8 minutes).

At this point I want to cancel the deployment, but I don't know how to stop the endless "Deploying" loop.

**Background**

Examining the activity log shows that the blueprint assignment is getting stuck provisioning a key vault. The logs show the following three operations repeated many many times with each set reappearing at 3 minute intervals:

1. Update Key Vault - Started
2. 'audit' Policy action. - Succeeded
3. Update Key Vault - Failed

The error reported in the failure is "InternalServerError - Internal Server Error (HTTP Status Code: 500)"

**Attempting to unassign in a "Deploying" state**
[image: Attempting to unassign in a "Deploying" state]

**Activity Log showing infinite loop**
[image: Activity Log showing infinite loop]

**Attempted Solutions**

I've tried clicking "Unassign blueprint" in the DevOps Blueprint page on the offending assignment but get the error:
Removing blueprint assignment 'BLUEPRINT-NAME'.
The operation is not allowed when assignment is in 'Deploying' state.

I also tried removing it using powershell:
Remove-AzBlueprintAssignment -Name $blueprintAssignmentName -SubscriptionId $sub
but received the same error:
The operation is not allowed when assignment is in 'Deploying' state.

Is there any way to cancel this assignment while it's deploying?

Comment: From what I can find, there is no way to cancel a "Stuck" deployment like this. Fortunately, they do time out after 2-3 hours which solved my problem. If anyone does know a way to cancel a blueprint assignment stuck in the "Deploying" state, I'd still be interested.

Comment: As you mentioned that I've tried clicking "Unassign blueprint" in the DevOps Blueprint page on the offending assignment, can you share a screenshot about this page? In addition, did you deploy the Azure blueprint assignment in the Azure DevOps pipeline?

Comment: Thanks @WalterQian-MSFT - I've updated the my question with some additional screenshots. 1) I attached a screenshot of trying to unassign the blueprint assignment from the DevOps Blueprint page. 2) This is deployed in the azure devops pipeline